# htaccess ssl redirect excluding a folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

Thank you in advance for your help,

I am having an issue, i already have an ssl for cp.domain.com and i am using the free lets encrypt for domain.com

however when i create a mod rewrite to force ssl on domain.com, when i goto access cp.domain.com it forwards me to domain.com/cp

The issue i have with this is that the software has been licensed for cp.domain.com so i get a license error when directed to domain.com/cp

Does all this make sense?

Anyone can help me out with this?

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.co\.uk$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^shared\-business\-hosting\.php$ "http\:\/\/domain\.co\.uk\/premium\-hosting\.php" [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.co\.uk$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^dedicated\-servers$ "http\:\/\/domain\.co\.uk\/dedicated\-servers\.php" [R=301,L]
    ErrorDocument 404 https://domain.co.uk/404.php
```

Comment: Can you share your `.htaccess` file where you're rewriting?

Comment: hi i have added the htaccess above thanks again

Comment: Can anyone shed some light onto this? your help is much appreciated